# "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" when connecting to Teradata with pyodbc on Windows

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a Teradata database using the following python snippet:

```
con = pyodbc.connect("Provider = Teradata; DBCNAME = teradata-dev,
      database = mydatabase UID = myuserid, PWD = mypassword")
```

Database, UID, and PWD hold non-dummy values. The data source is defined in "32-bit ODBC administrator"

I get the following error message:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data 
source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have no problem connecting using R's RODBC packge. What am I doing wrong?

OS: Windows 7 professional 64 bit

Teradata Driver: 32 bit, version 14.10.00.00

Python: 32 bit, Python 2.7.10 | Anaconda 2.3.0

UPDATE:

I've tried a different connection string:

```
"sConn=ODBC;Driver={Teradata};DSN=teradata-dev;database=mydatabase;
UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword"
```

and now I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('28000', '[28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Not 
enough information to log on (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] 
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Not enough information to log on (0)')
```

UPDATE #2:

I got it to work correctly by using the DSN directly.

"DSN = dsninODBC;USN = myusername;PWD = mypassword"

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database in windows using ODBC?

Comment: Yes, and I am able to connect using the RODBC package in R.